# Java Using Types From Unrelated Packages

Tags: java, types, package

Consider the javafx.util.Builder interface --  could it be used generally to indicate some class (that implements this interface) follows the builder pattern?

Of course, this interface is probably intended to be used by JavaFX applications to assist in creating domain objects or something along those lines.

This interface name and its abstract method is very well written such that it can be applied more broadly, e.g. as in the Builder Design Pattern.  With design patterns, it can be used in any application, not just JavaFX application.  Therefore, this javafx.util.Builder interface could appear in a web application, as an example.  This could gives rise to mixing up types (interface or class) appearing in any context.  From a general design and code practices, is this consider poor practice?

Of course, if types are used from unrelated packages, the documentations for such types are carefully observed and implemented such that the behaviour and whatnot follows the documented specification.  Having said all of that, and if a type from an unrelated package does still fit the bill, can it be used?  Or should a new type declaration be made and use that instead?

Returning to the beginning example of the builder design pattern, could the javafx.util.Builder type be used represent the builder design pattern, or should a general one be created: e.g. public interface com.example.Builder?